# update database using java stream

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-stream

I need to update the Compliance status of OrderLines of an Order with a button "refresh status" in front page, and this backend methods ""works"".

In fact, my front refresh and show me the new Data in the column "Compliance status", and my snackbar notification open a pop-up with "X order lines have been updated"

But, if i refresh 'F5' my page or if i check my database, the older data are still here.

Can someone explain me why ?

Status availables are : ONGOING, COMPLIANT, NOTCOMPLIANT, NO_DATA, TO_CHECK

This happens ONLY when before refresh, status are <> "NO_DATA" and after refresh status are "NO_DATA". ("NO_DATA" means suppliers does not provide data -> Generally when the production is permanently stopped).

In debug mode withy IntelliJ, we can see the

- "FROM" value = for example, "ONGOING"
- "TO" value = in this case, "NO_DATA"

but only the "FROM" data "ONGOING" is in my column or my database.

My service

```html
  @Transactional
  public List<ComplianceEventDto> refreshComplianceStatuses(String shipmentReleaseId) {
    log.debug("Finding compliance statuses from shipment release: '{}'...", shipmentReleaseId);
    final Specification<ShipmentRelease> shipmentReleaseSpecification = byId(UUID.fromString(shipmentReleaseId)).and(fetchOrder());
    // find shipment release from identifier
    final ShipmentRelease shipmentRelease = shipmentReleaseRepository.findOne(shipmentReleaseSpecification)
      .orElseThrow(ShipmentReleaseNotFoundException::new);

    // find all lines
    final Order order = shipmentRelease.getOrder();
    final Specification<ShipmentReleaseOrderLine> specification = byOrder(order).and(fetchOrderLine()).and(byShipmentRelease(shipmentRelease));
    final List<ShipmentReleaseOrderLine> shipmentReleaseOrderLines = shipmentReleaseOrderLineRepository.findAll(specification);

    log.info("Finding compliance statuses from '{}' shipment release order lines ...", shipmentReleaseOrderLines.size());
     return shipmentReleaseOrderLines.stream()
      .map(ShipmentReleaseOrderLine::getOrderLine)
      .distinct()
      .filter(orderLine -> !complianceService.findStatus(orderLine).equals(ComplianceStatus.COMPLIANT))
      .map(orderLine -> {
        ComplianceStatus from = orderLine.getComplianceStatus();
        ComplianceStatus to = complianceService.findQmsComplianceStatuses(orderLine.getOrder(), orderLine.getProduct());
        log.info("Order line: '{}' compliance status has been updated from '{}' to '{}'", orderLine, from, to);
        final ComplianceEventDto complianceEventDto = new ComplianceEventDto();
        complianceEventDto.setFrom(ComplianceEventDto.FromEnum.valueOf(from.toString()));
        complianceEventDto.setTo(ComplianceEventDto.ToEnum.valueOf(to.toString()));
        complianceEventDto.setProductId(orderLine.getProduct().getId().toString());
        complianceEventDto.setOrderLineId(orderLine.getId().toString());
        return complianceEventDto;
      })
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```

My Controller

```html
  @Override
  public ResponseEntity<List<ComplianceEventDto>> refreshCompliance(String shipmentReleaseId) {
    final List<ComplianceEventDto> complianceStatuses = shipmentReleaseService.refreshComplianceStatuses(shipmentReleaseId);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(complianceStatuses, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

Maybe the source of this error is somewhere else, i can share you others parts to helping. thanks

Comment: don't see in your code that you write anything to the database, so it should be no wonder that nothing is found in the database

Comment: And how i can write something to update my database.
My stream output is an List of ComplianceEventDto with this schema :
{
0 : {
   orderLineId : "UUID",
   productId : "UUID",
   from : "ONGOING",
   to : "NO_DATA"
},
1 : ....}

And this is the value of "to" that i want to save in my table order_line, in column ComplianceStatus